# Criar JFrame com label?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Como criar um **JFrame**, que contenha uma **JLabel** com texto, e que possa ser posicionada em qualquer lugar do frame.

Preciso que essa label possa ficar em qualquer lugar da area do frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package teste02;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TelaSistema extends JFrame 
{
    public TelaSistema() 
    {
        setSize(600, 400);       
        setTitle("Sistema "); 
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(null);        
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label = new JLabel("Olá mundo !");
        painel.add(label);
        label.setBounds(250, 150, 300, 50);
        add(painel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }      

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TelaSistema teste = new TelaSistema();
    }
}
```

Comment: Da uma procurada antes de postar as perguntas, pode ser que ja foram postas por aqui.

Comment: pode deixar, é que eu sou novo aqui, mas valeu! Obrigado, vou  testar o cod.

Comment: tem como mudar a cor do texto do label ?

Comment: @Javinha tem sim. Uma maneira bem simples é implementar tags em HTML. Exemplo: <html>O campo <font color=#3061AB>  texto aqui </font> </html>

Comment: Pra que usar html se o jlabel tem recurso nativo? Outra coisa, deve-se evitar usar posição absoluta, a não ser que isso seja de extrema necessidade, isso torna a construção da tela e adição de componentes altamente complexo, por isso existe os layoutmanagers, para fazer o "trabalho pesado" de posicionar para gente.

Comment: `jLabel1.setForeground(Color.red);` por exemplo, desse jeito muda pra cor vermelha. Veja mais cores na [documentação da classe Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, eu testei as duas maneiras para as cores. O HTML resolveu melhor, devido a quantidade de palavras que eu editei dentro do texto, e quanto ao posicionamento, era extremamente necessário. Obrigado novamente !